# Unknown external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, linker

I've been trying to solve this linker error for the last 3 hours, I keep getting errors saying that I have unresolved external symbol of _WinMainCRTStartup. Does anyone know what could be causing this error? I am using SDL's main function definition (SDL_main)

I also tried recreating the project incase something was accidentally changed, but the error persists.

The full output is here
https://gist.github.com/Joshhua5/73fe4235724d95e53f48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting lots of unresolved external symbols, not just `_WinMainCRTStartup`. This usually indicates you're not linking a library you need to, and given the names of the functions it looks like it's the C runtime library (controlled with the `/MTd` etc. flags, or "C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library" in the project properties dialogue.

I think I see the problem though; this line near the bottom:

```
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'UNKNOWN' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

... suggests you're using the VS2015 preview, and I don't imagine there's a release of SDL for that toolset yet, so I guess you're linking old libraries (which expect to be linked with an older toolset). Is that right? If so, you'll need to build SDL yourself.

Another possibility is simply that you've got the wrong subsystem type set - SDL will be expecting either `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` or `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` (set in "Linker -> System -> SubSystem"). Try choosing whichever one isn't chosen now.

Comment: I currently am compiling sdl myself and I got the same issues with Visual Studio 2013 (installed it just to test if it was 2015)

I've tried between console and windows

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're compiling SDL with the same settings as your app? The 'conflict' message in the output suggests not. I've never seen a machine type of 'UNKNOWN' so that's kind of weird. Perhaps try explicitly using `/MACHINE:X86` when compiling SDL. Other settings that must match are C runtime type, Unicode usage, exception handling support, linker `/DEBUG` flag, and some others, though it certainly looks like it's the machine type that's mismatched.

Comment: I definitely have it and added in your commands to make sure.

Comment: It is something with SDL2 because I created a new project, with an empty SDL_main and I got the same errors.

Comment: Ok, I just had a quick look at SDL how it's built; their build system is pretty complex so it's possible they have some Visual Studio version-specific stuff in there that hasn't yet been updated to work with the VS2015 preview. Best place to ask would be the SDL community as to me it sounds like you're doing everything right.

Comment: I had it working previously, but i don't recall changing any settings. Thanks for your help, ill try recreating all my project files.